# sbt subproject source folders not created automatically?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using sbt version 1.1.4.  I have my subprojects build like so:

```
val testDeps = Seq(
  "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.5",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test"
)

libraryDependencies ++= testDeps

lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
  .aggregate(
    common,
    analytics,
    website
  )

lazy val common = project.in(file("common"))
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= testDeps
  )

lazy val analytics = project.in(file("analytics"))
  .dependsOn(common)
  .settings()

lazy val website = project.in(file("website"))
  .dependsOn(common)
  .settings()
```

I am unable to get sbt to automatically generate the `src/scala/...` folders automatically, how does one do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sbt doesn't create source folders automatically. If you want to do it, you can write a little task for it:

```
lazy val createSourceDirs = taskKey[Unit]("Creates source directories for all subprojects")

Global / createSourceDirs := {
  val log = streams.value.log
  val srcDirs = sourceDirectory.all(ScopeFilter(inAnyProject)).value
  srcDirs.foreach { src =>
    val dir = src / "main" / "scala"
    if (dir.exists) log.info(s"Skipping existing ${dir}")
    else {
      IO.createDirectory(dir)
      log.info(s"Created ${dir}")
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure this is very useful, but the fact is, you *can* do it. And if you often need it, add it to your `~/.sbt/1.0/global.sbt` and use in any project.